# How do I use Nokogiri to parse a single file with multiple XML documents in it?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have a single file that contains multiple concatenated XML files like so:

```
<?xml version ... ?>
<!DOCTYPE ... >
...
<?xml version ... ?>
<!DOCTYPE ... >
...
<?xml version ... ?>
<!DOCTYPE ... >
...
```

Is there any way to parse the file as is, using Nokogiri, as opposed to slicing the file up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to slice it into individual documents, but that is an easy thing to do.

Ruby's [`String.split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split) method makes it easy. For instance if variable `foo` contains the text, then `foo.split("<?xml version ... ?>\n")` will return an array you can loop over:

```
foo.split("<?xml version ... ?>\n")
[
    [0] "",
    [1] "<!DOCTYPE ... >\n...\n",
    [2] "<!DOCTYPE ... >\n...\n",
    [3] "<!DOCTYPE ... >\n..."
]
```

Parse each of those chunks and you'll be on your way. You might need to prepend the XML DECL statement to make Nokogiri happy, but I think it'll do OK without it.

Comment: that's what i've been doing, i was afraid there was no clean way around it. unfortunately the file itself is rather large (>100MB) and i have no control over the generating source.

Comment: If the file is too big for memory, which 100MB isn't on most machines for a temporary load, then you could write something that walks through the file, splits it into its component files, then processes them separately.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be a valid XML file, so you can't parse it all in one go. But you may be able to create a class that inherits from File, and has the smarts to return end-of-file when you get to the end of each XML document. With that, you should be able to open your file once, but you would still make multiple calls to your XML parser.

If the XML fragments are not very large, it may be best to slurp a fragment at at time into a string variable (perhaps using regexp), and parse that.